# Magento 2: Url_rewrite not working for migrated product magento 2

Tags: magento2

Magento 2: Url_rewrite not working for migrated product magento 2
Whenever we changes url key for migrated product then its not affect on url_rewrite table and not redirect to new one url.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check for this .... I hope it will work for you

[The new url key is not working for product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244801/the-new-url-key-is-not-working-for-product-page)

It is related to your issue